# 'NSInternalInconsistencyException' - unable to push uitableviewcontroller on uinavigationcontroller ios 6

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, crash, uitableview, pushviewcontroller

I am simply pushing a `UITableviewController` to navigation stack. Code works fine in both iOS 4.3 and 5 but crashes in iOS 6. Exception is:

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "MenuController" nib but the view outlet was not set.'**

I know this exception is raised when view outlet is not set. Outlet is set automatically by IB as you can see in figure, but still the same. What am I doing wrong?

Simple code pushing the controller:

```cs
MenuController *menu = [[MenuController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    menu.title = @"Watches";
    menu.MenuToBeDisplayed = @"main menu";
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:menu animated:YES];
```

[image]

**Stack trace is:**

```cs
 0   CoreFoundation                      0x01f3e02e __exceptionPreprocess + 206
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01a12e7e objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x01f3ddeb +[NSException raise:format:] + 139
    3   UIKit                               0x00a3af18 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 505
    4   UIKit                               0x00a3b418 -[UIViewController loadView] + 302
    5   UIKit                               0x00b8934e -[UITableViewController loadView] + 80
    6   UIKit                               0x00a3b648 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 73
    7   UIKit                               0x00a3b882 -[UIViewController view] + 33
    8   UIKit                               0x00a3bb2a -[UIViewController contentScrollView] + 36
    9   UIKit                               0x00a52ef5 -[UINavigationController _computeAndApplyScrollContentInsetDeltaForViewController:] + 36
    10  UIKit                               0x00a52fdb -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 43
    11  UIKit                               0x00a53286 -[UINavigationController _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 254
    12  UIKit                               0x00a53381 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 72
    13  UIKit                               0x00a53eab -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 386
    14  UIKit                               0x00a544a3 -[UINavigationController pushViewController:transition:forceImmediate:] + 1030
    15  UIKit                               0x00a54098 -[UINavigationController pushViewController:animated:] + 62
    16  Tick                                0x000e5f02 -[MarketWatchViewController openMenu] + 274
    17  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01a26705 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
    18  UIKit                               0x0095d920 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 96
    19  UIKit                               0x00b99b24 -[UIBarButtonItem(UIInternal) _sendAction:withEvent:] + 139
    20  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01a26705 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
    21  UIKit                               0x0095d920 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 96
    22  UIKit                               0x0095d8b8 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
    23  UIKit                               0x00a1e671 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
    24  UIKit                               0x00a1ebcf -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 578
    25  UIKit                               0x00a1dd38 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 546
    26  UIKit                               0x0098d33f -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 846
    27  UIKit                               0x0098d552 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 273
    28  UIKit                               0x0096b3aa -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 436
    29  UIKit                               0x0095ccf8 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 9874
    30  GraphicsServices                    0x0291adf9 _PurpleEventCallback + 339
    31  GraphicsServices                    0x0291aad0 PurpleEventCallback + 46
    32  CoreFoundation                      0x01eb3bf5 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
    33  CoreFoundation                      0x01eb3962 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 146
    34  CoreFoundation                      0x01ee4bb6 __CFRunLoopRun + 2118
    35  CoreFoundation                      0x01ee3f44 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 276
    36  CoreFoundation                      0x01ee3e1b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    37  GraphicsServices                    0x029197e3 GSEventRunModal + 88
    38  GraphicsServices                    0x02919668 GSEventRun + 104
    39  UIKit                               0x0095a65c UIApplicationMain + 1211
    40  Tick                                0x00002dc5 main + 197
    41  Tick                                0x00002cb5 start + 53
```

**EDIT:**

I have removed nib file, and also `initWithNibName:` method, but I am still getting this stupid exception since yesterday. This will drive me crazy :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With

`MenuController *menu = [[MenuController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];`

You aren't using your xib file at all becouse for initing contreoller with xib you need to use

`initWithNibName:bundle:` instead of `initWithStyle:`

and then set your controller's class on xib like this

[image: setting xib's controllers custom class]

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am using this in three files. Its working fine in two, but don't know why its messing up with call in one file only.

Comment: I also tried using initWithNibName:bundle: but this didn't work too.

Comment: Try clean project and delete app from simulator or device, and then try again may be there is some problems with xib files

Comment: I deleted my app again, restarted xcode and now it is working fine!! Still unable to figure out what was reason of exception. Any ways thanks.